# How to clear underlines after disabling flyspell?

Tags: flyspell

There are already questions on disabling flyspell (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423638)

However I would like to toggle flyspell at runtime.

An annoyance I've found is the red-underline persists, even once flyspell has been disabled.

Closing and opening the file refreshes, but that's impractical.

eg:

```
(turn-off-flyspell)
(flyspell-mode 0)

;; force refresh of highlighting (doesn't work)
(font-lock-fontify-buffer)
```

Is there a way to clear underlined text?

Answer (score 2):

`flyspell-delete-all-overlays` is a built-in non-interactive function, which is called by `turn-off-flyspell`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it works but for some reason I need to call it directly.   `(flyspell-mode 0) (turn-off-flyspell)` fails. Adding `(flyspell-delete-all-overlays)` afterwards works.

Comment: It sounds like something is interfering with turning off `flyspell-mode` in your setup, e.g., buffer narrowed, indirect-buffer is involved in the equation, ...  You might want to spend some time working with a minimal example and then gradually work-up to your full-setup until you track down what is causing the interference ....